# Different heights of content divs on different pages

Tags: css, html

Having just learned css/html using divs about a year ago (coming from tables) I am confused on how I can make a single div be at different heights on different pages without making unique divs for every page due to their position, height, etc.

I hope I am pasting this correctly.

Example of CSS Code for 3 pages

```
#homeBody { position:absolute; height: 728px; width: 900px; top: 131px; left: 394px;             background-color:#E0DDB6; left: 50%; margin-left: -450px; }
#homeFooter { position:absolute; height: 100px; width: 900px; top: 890px; left: 394px; left: 50%; margin-left: -450px; }

#worksBody { position:absolute; height: 469px; width: 900px; top: 131px; left: 394px; background-color:#E0DDB6; left: 50%; margin-left: -450px; }
#worksFooter { position:absolute; height: 100px; width: 900px; top: 630px; left: 394px; left: 50%; margin-left: -450px; }

#contactBody { position:absolute; height: 500px; width: 900px; top: 131px; left: 394px; background-color:#E0DDB6; left: 50%; margin-left: -450px; }
#contactFooter { position:absolute; height: 100px; width: 900px; top: 661px; left: 394px; left: 50%; margin-left: -450px; }
```

Too much work, I know. There has to be an easier way, I just don't know how to achieve it or what to search for. How can I created divs that can be re-used rather than unique div for every page?

I have been messing around with css and have successfully created a div that can be used on different pages, but requires &nbsp to create the height of the #content div.

Example of my current CSS

```
body { background-color: #716B5B; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-image:     url(../background/background.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top;     min-height: 100%; }
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html { height: 100%; }

#content { background-color:#E0DDB6; margin-bottom: 155px; top:140px; width: 900px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; position:relative; }
#footer { position: relative; bottom:0; width: 900px; height: 155px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
```

I am able to position divs with images, text, etc inside the #content div while having the #footer land underneath no matter what the length of #content is, but can only achieve this by adding &nbsp's inside the #content div.

A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Div's are `block` elements, they take up as much height as their content and with is by default 100%.

Comment: @user3386673, for your &nbsp; problem. Try adding this to your css:

    ".clear {
        clear: both;
    }"

then add between your content div and footer div this:

    "<div class='clear'></div>"

Comment: Thanks guys. I found that if I place a <style> tag on each page with different height values, I could easily control unique lengths of each page.

Page 1
<style #content {height:500px;}</style>

Page 2
<style #content {height:950px;}</style>

I never knew I could do this. I only ever maintained 1-2 css pages style.css and layout.css (placement of div ids) for the entire website. This solves my &nbsp as well.

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Other than changing how you do this there is no nice way to do it.

Personally I would lay it out with id's and classes.

Example CSS:

```
#home .body {}
#home .footer {}

etc...
```

Example HTML:

```
<div id='home' class='body'>Content Here For Home Body</div>
<div id='home' class='footer'>Content Here For Home Footer</div>
```

---

You could also have separate css files for each page so you would be able to split up the css content. But this could make it more tedious to edit.

Comment: Thanks for your input ShinyTuxedo, I will try your method of css structure. cheers.